# XML Parsing with libxml in C is not showing attribute name

Tags: c, parsing, xhtml, libxml2

I am trying to parse a XHTML file and get the attributes and its values.Using libxml.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libxml/HTMLparser.h>
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h> 
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

void walkTree(xmlNode * a_node)
{
  xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;
  xmlAttr *cur_attr = NULL;
  for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) {
     // do something with that node information, like… printing the tag’s name and attributes
     printf("Got tag : %s\n", cur_node->name);
     for (cur_attr = cur_node->properties; cur_attr; cur_attr = cur_attr->next) {
     printf("  -> with attribute : %s\n", cur_attr->name);
     printf("     -> with Value: %s\n", (cur_attr->children)->name);
}
walkTree(cur_node->children);
}
}
int main(void)
{  
// Load XHTML
char *data;
data = "<html><body class=\"123\" damn=\"123\"></html>";

int len = strlen(data) + 1;
htmlParserCtxtPtr parser = htmlCreatePushParserCtxt(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
htmlCtxtUseOptions(parser, HTML_PARSE_NOBLANKS | HTML_PARSE_NOERROR | HTML_PARSE_NOWARNING | HTML_PARSE_NONET);
htmlParseChunk(parser, data, len, 0);
htmlParseChunk(parser, NULL, len, 1);
walkTree(xmlDocGetRootElement(parser->myDoc));

 }
```

I was expecting this output

```
 Got tag: html
Got tag: body
-> with attribute: class
  -> with value: 123
-> with attribute: damn
  -> with value: 123
```

But I got this ouptput unfortunately:

```
 Got tag: html
Got tag: body
-> with attribute: class
  -> with value: text
-> with attribute: damn
  -> with value: text
```

I have tried with other html codes too no matter what the attribute value is it always shows "text" instead of the value.

Why? how to fix it? How to get the real attribute value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be very easily achieved by modifying a line of code.xmlNodeGetContent() because it accepts  xmlNode.Unlike xmlGetProp() which accepts xmlNodePtr.So best to use xmlNodeGetContent() to get attribute of a node when using xmlNode or xmlAttr. Hope that helps :)

here is the solution:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <libxml/HTMLparser.h>
 #include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
 #include <libxml/tree.h>
 #include <libxml/parser.h>
 void walkTree(xmlNode * a_node)
 {
    xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;
    xmlAttr *cur_attr = NULL;
    xmlChar *attr;
    for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) {
    // do something with that node information, like… printing the tag’s name and attributes
    printf("Got tag : %s\n", cur_node->name);
    for (cur_attr = cur_node->properties; cur_attr; cur_attr = cur_attr->next) {

       printf("  -> with attribute : %s\n", cur_attr->name);

       // This part fixed the code :D 
       attr =  xmlNodeGetContent(cur_attr);

      printf("     -> with Value: %s\n", attr);
    }
   walkTree(cur_node->children);
}
}
int main(void)
{
// Load XHTML
char *data;
data = "<html><body class=\"123\" damn=\"123\"></html>";

    int len = strlen(data) + 1;
    htmlParserCtxtPtr parser = htmlCreatePushParserCtxt(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
     htmlCtxtUseOptions(parser, HTML_PARSE_NOBLANKS | HTML_PARSE_NOERROR | HTML_PARSE_NOWARNING | HTML_PARSE_NONET);
     htmlParseChunk(parser, data, len, 0);
     htmlParseChunk(parser, NULL, len, 1);
     walkTree(xmlDocGetRootElement(parser->myDoc));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of poking around in the attribute structure directly, how about using `xmlGetProp`, according to the method [here](http://xmlsoft.org/tutorial/ar01s08.html):

```
void
getReference (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr cur) {

    xmlChar *uri;
    cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"reference"))) {
            uri = xmlGetProp(cur, "uri");
            printf("uri: %s\n", uri);
            xmlFree(uri);
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return;
}
```

What I think is happening is that the child of the attribute node is a text node with the text as the *contents* and not the name. But using the API provided will hide all this from you. And also provide some error checking (e.g. if `children` is `NULL`).

Comment: It is not working it tried it because in my code it will pass XmlNode but there it takes XmlNodePtr.

Comment: `XmlNode` is a `struct`. `XmlNodePtr` is just a pointer to that `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

A minor correction to the answer by Khaled:

```
 void walkTree(xmlNode * a_node)
 {
    xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;
    xmlAttr *cur_attr = NULL;
    xmlChar *attr;
    for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) {
    // do something with that node information, like… printing the tag’s name and attributes
    printf("Got tag : %s\n", cur_node->name);
    for (cur_attr = cur_node->properties; cur_attr; cur_attr = cur_attr->next) {

       printf("  -> with attribute : %s\n", cur_attr->name);

       // CORRECTION HERE
       attr =  xmlNodeGetContent(cur_attr->children);

      printf("     -> with Value: %s\n", attr);
    }
   walkTree(cur_node->children);
}
}
```

Without this it would print the same atribute value for different attributes in the same tag.